# Best book of Lie groups after Hall's one

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

I am about to finish reading Hall's *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations*, and searching for the next book.

I am poor at differential geometry but good at algebra, including Lie algebras. Indeed, I know much about representation theory of finite dimensional Lie algebras, and a little about that of infinite dimension.

What would be the best book for me of general theory of Lie group representations? Or should I learn more about geometry before reading further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Anthony Knapp's *Lie groups beyond an introduction* is a good choice.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I will go to the library and find it.